# Omit unused grid lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

How do I hide grid lines on the x axis for which there are no values? My script:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x=n,y=value,color=variable)) + geom_line()+
  labs(color="Legend")+
  scale_x_continuous("x",expand=c(0,0),
                     breaks=c(1,2,5,10,30,60))+
  scale_y_continuous("y",expand=c(0,0),
                      breaks=round(seq(0,0.8),by=0.1),1))
```

Data (there will be more variables later):

```
n variable     value
1        1 0.2339010
2        1 0.2625115
5        1 0.2781600
10        1 0.2776770
30        1 0.3344481
60        1 0.4810225
```

This makes my graph look as following. However, I only want to show the white grid lines for x = 1, 2, 5, 10, 30 and 60 (so for all values of n). How do I omit all the other (unused lines)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the minor breaks to NULL,

```
scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = NULL)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!